# Is there a reason to do a cast when throwing an exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I recently came across an odd-to-me pattern in two completely independent bits of Java code: casting something that is already a `Throwable` to a more specific exception class when throwing. E.g., the following is from some Tomcat code:

```
Exception exception = ex.getException();
if (exception instanceof IOException) {
    throw (IOException) exception;
}
```

The cast to `IOException` seems entirely pointless to me, but having seen similar twice in the wild, I wonder if I'm missing something?

Comment: Related reading (if you're on Java 7): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast tells the compiler what kind of exception it is, and therefore whether it's "checked" or "unchecked".

Comment: *smacks forehead* Ahh, of course. Beyond that, it allows that method to comply with its 'throws IOException' declaration. Thanks.